# A question about permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am taking a course in abstract algebra, and have a question regarding this idea.

I am being asked to show, after having proven that an r-cycle is a conjugate to its own inverse (there is an x such that $xPx^{-1} = P^{-1}$ ), I am now being asked to show that said x's don't necessarily have to move every point. This is a pretty obvious conclusion, considering the fact that if $P$ is an r-cycle of an odd number, then the middle number does not have to move in order to get it to the $P^{-1}$ form.

Any hints or help would be appreciated... Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you answered your own question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Prove that **in general**, for two $\;r$-cycles $\;(a_1\ldots a_r)\;,\;(b_1\ldots b_r)\;$ , we have that

$$(a_1\ldots a_r)=\pi(b_1\ldots b_r)\pi^{-1}$$

with $\;\pi\;$ the permutation defined by

$$\pi(x):=\begin{cases}b_i&,\;\;\text{if}\;\;x=a_i\\{}\\x&,\;\;\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Could you clarify your definition of /pi ? I am not quite sure I understand. How could /pi be applied to the r-cycle (b_1,...b_r) if /pi(x)=b_i when x=a_i.

Comment: Suppose all the permutations belong to $\;S_n\;,\;\;n\ge r\;$ , then each such permutation can be seen as a bijection of the set $\;\{1,2,...,n\}\;$ . Well, there's the definition of the **function** $\;\pi:\{1,2,...,n\}\to\{1,2,...,n\}\;$ . To check it is a bijection is a rather easy exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here, but it seems as though you simply need to provide a counter example (i.e. a specific instance in which an $r$-cycle is sent to its inverse via conjugation by some element $x$ such that $x$ has at least one fixed point.) Providing a counter example is the most common rigorous proof technique used to disprove a proposition.

The simpler the example the better, so I would suggest using

$$ P = (1,2,3), x=(1,2).$$

Comment: "Counterexample"? No, the claim is true: two cycles (in a permutation group) are conjugate iff they have the very same length, and this is the case with any cycle and its inverse.